# What is the cleanest way to add code to contrib.auth

Tags: django, joomla, overriding, subclass

I've migrated an old joomla installation over to django. The password hashes is an issue though. I had to modify the get_hexdigest in contrib.auth.models to have an extra if statement to reverse the way the hash is generated.

```
# Custom for Joomla
if algorithm == 'joomla':
    return md5_constructor(raw_password + salt).hexdigest()
# Djangos original md5
if algorithm == 'md5':
    return md5_constructor(salt + raw_password).hexdigest()
```

I also added the following to the User model to update the passwords after login if they have the old joomla style:

```
# Joomla Backwards compat
algo, salt, hsh = self.password.split('$')
if algo == 'joomla':
    is_correct = (hsh == get_hexdigest(algo, salt, raw_password))
    if is_correct:
        # Convert the password to the new more secure format.
        self.set_password(raw_password)
        self.save()
    return is_correct
```

Everything is working perfectly but I'd rather not edit this code directly in the django tree. Is there a cleaner way to do this in my own project?

Thanks

Comment: for the record: in terms of security, it's better to have the salt first (see: http://programming.arantius.com/how-to-salt-your-hash)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I wasn't aware of that. But in this case I cant change it. I'm dealing with legacy data from Joomla and they do it the other way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet would be to roll a custom auth backend and rewrite get_hexdigest in there. Never done it myself, but documentation on how to do so is available at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-backends.

Comment: +1: I spent days of my life to do it correctly in my scenario, but in your case it should be quite easy to do and is the most "Djangoic" way to go.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of custom auth backends, but since I found this stuff in the models.py I didnt think it applied. After your link I reread it all and thats exactly one I need. Circle gets the Square!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the guidance.  For anyone who needs to go the other way (`DJango` to `Joomla`) with DJ passwords, the DJ format is `Sha1$salt$crypt`.

`Joomla` standard auth plugin and joomla core `JUserHelper` do not implement the same SHA1 algorithum but it is fairly easy to patch into joomla.php in that plugin, where the plugin normally does an explode on `':'`.  Do a three-part explode with `'$'` and use `salt = [1]`, compare that against  `$encrypted = sha1($salt.$plaintext)`, match that against the `crypt [2]`.